# httpClient can not retain cookie with many async request in my android app

Tags: java, android, cookies, httpclient

i am using HttpClient and ClientConnectionManager to manage http request in andorid. the following MyHttp class is the only class to process all http method.

BUT with many async http request, i found the httpClient can not send correct cookie. for example , in my application ,there are five request at the app start.but there are two type of cookies get from and send to the server. on server side. could you give me any adivse?

PS: 
i have another web project and ios project using the same api server,they are all correct on the cookie processing.

MyHttp is  instantiation in my BaseActivity which extends Activtiy

```
public class MyHttp {
    public static HttpClient  httpClient;
    public static HttpContext localContext;

    public MyHttp() {

    }

    public String getHttp(String url) throws Exception {
        String result = "";
        HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(url);
        getMethod.addHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getMethod,localContext);

        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
            result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "utf-8");
        }    
        return result;
    }



    public static synchronized HttpClient getHttpClient() {
        /**cookie*/
        CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        // Create local HTTP context
        localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        // Bind custom cookie store to the local context
        localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
        if (null == httpClient) {
            // 初始化工作
            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();

            HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

            // 设置http https支持
            SchemeRegistry schReg = new SchemeRegistry();
            schReg.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory
                    .getSocketFactory(), 80));
            schReg.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

            ClientConnectionManager conManager = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(
                    params, schReg);

            httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(conManager, params);
        }
        return httpClient;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `getHttpClient()` method you are creating a new instance of the `BasicCookieStore` and `BasicHttpContext` on each call. This will cause different cookie stores to be used at different times and this may lead to the loss of cookies.

I would recommend you instantiate the `localContext` only once and reuse this instance every time you do a request.

**P.S.** I would really suggest you not to use `HttpClient`. It won't be supported anymore by Google and you shouldn't invest time it it. It's better to use `HttpUrlConnection`, or some of the HTTP communication frameworks that are available - Volley, OkHttp, Retrofit, etc.

Comment: ok, i would accept your suggestion and go to use HttpUrlConnection, but before that , my getHttpClient is a  static synchronized  method ,in my understanding it wouldn't be call mutiple times.  sorry i am really java newbee, correct me if i am wrong

Comment: static and synchronized don't limit the number of times a method can be called. The synchronized keyword just guarantees you that it is safe to call this from multiple threads at the same time. How do you use this function in your activity? Do you call it each time you need to obtain a reference to a HttpClient?

Comment: oh, yes, i thought the method be called only once because i place the call in application's onCreate method,but when i add a log in the onCreate method, i find the log be printed twice

Comment: Now just make sure you are instantiating the local context only once and using the same cookie store, and you should be good to go.